# Build: Failed to parse file 'C:/.../tsconfig.json/tsconfig.json': Invalid character. C:\..\VSTSC

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5

Learning TypeScript and Visual Studio is complaining:

> Build: Failed to parse file 'C:/.../tsconfig.json/tsconfig.json': Invalid character.  C:..\VSTSC

Strangely, there is no tsconfig.json/tsconfig.json file. There is only a tsconfig.json file.

My tsconfig.json file is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
      "target" : "es5",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "rootDir": "src"        
  }
}
```

Visual Studio has stopped transpiling my TypeScript. How can I resolve this issue?

Excluding tsconfig.json resolve the issue... but is there another way?

Is it because of this message?

> Your project file uses an older version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than supported by this version of Visual Studio.  Your project may be using TypeScript language features that will result in errors when compiling with this version of the TypeScript tools.  To remove this warning, remove the  element from your project file

Comment: I get the same error with a clean install of VS 2015 (pro) Update 2 and using the latest TypeScript (1.8.4).
VS wants to control TypeScript options through a tab on the project properties page, but disables this tab if there is a tsconfig.json file present.
The tsconfig.json file is valid (vsCode works with it) but VS2016 throws this misleading exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio prompted a warning to show up that I had previously ignored. The solution is right in the warning:

> Your project file uses an older version of the TypeScript compiler and tools than supported by this version of Visual Studio. Your project may be using TypeScript language features that will result in errors when compiling with this version of the TypeScript tools. To remove this warning, remove the element from your project file

Removing it solved the problem... but then I believe I am forced to use the installed version of TypeScript.